# Existence of an element in a Hopf algebra that satisfies a 'flip' property

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, hopf-algebras

Consider a Hopf algebra $H$ where $S$ is the antipode and $\Delta$ is the coproduct. Given $a \in H$, I want to know if there always exists an element $b \in H$ satisfying the 'flip' property: $$\Delta (b) (1 \otimes a) = Sa \otimes 1$$

I know that this property is satisfied for quantum double of $G$, which can be seen as follows. Let $\{k\}_{k \in G}$ be a basis for $\mathbb{C}(G)$ (group algebra) and let $\{g^*\}_{g \in G}$ be a basis for $\mathcal{F}(G)$ (space of complex valued functions over $G$). Then for any element $a = k g^*$, the element $b = \sum_{l \in G} k l^*$ does the job.

But is it a universal property of Hopf algebras? How can I see it if so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is surely false for general Hopf algebras. Applying the slice map $\epsilon \otimes \iota$ to the condition
$$\Delta(b)(1\otimes a)= Sa \otimes 1\tag{*}\label{star}$$
yields the weaker condition
$$ba = \epsilon(a)1.\tag{**}\label{starstar}$$

For example, let $k$ be a field and consider the Hopf algebra $k[x]$ with
$$\Delta(x) = 1 \otimes x + x\otimes 1, \quad \epsilon(x) = 0, \quad S(x) = -x.$$

Consider the element $a= x$. Then clearly there is no non-zero $b\in k[x]$ such that \eqref{starstar} holds, since $k[x]$ does not have zero divisors. Hence, there is no $b\in k[x]$ such that \eqref{star} holds. It is easy to come up with variations of this example that give other counterexamples.

Comment: Why is $b=0$ disallowed? If I read the question correctly $b$ is allowed to depend on $a$. Maybe you want to apply $\iota\otimes\varepsilon$ instead?

Comment: @AchimKrause $b=0$ does not satisfy $(*)$ in the example.

Comment: Thank you for the counterexample!